# GAE custom domain wildcard subdomain issues

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Whiles playing around with GAE custom domain setup in hopes of building a multi-tenant application. I noticed that wildcard sub domains don't quit work as documented.

for example, if one configures domain *.dev.example.com *.qa.example.com you would expect dev.example.com to automatically serve default services deployed in appengine, I however noticed that recently I would have to explicitly enter default.dev.example.com. This however is not what has been documented.

Anyone understands why this is now the case? the domains are verified with DNS configuration on Google DNS service. All works as expected, meaning that I can reach all other services on domain, but default service is not automatically been served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various attempts, I eventually purchased some Google support time. And the solution to this is that you need to create and map both a wildcard domain and naked domain. Therefore, one will need to have both

```
*.dev.example.com and dev.example.com
```

This is of course tedious, the good news is that Google is running alpha testing on API that allows domain mapping to happen automatically, register at [here](https://docs.google.com/a/edged.agency/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfixtu8XQRNSAIo-mCaHnrHsUJLcMj0cSjI_jMskP7YpgN0vA/viewform?c=0&w=1&fbzx=-778309122576269300)

Soon multi tenancy application deployments will require no manual intervention.

Comment: Can't register. Quote - "The form App Engine Admin API - Custom Domains & SSL Certificates - Alpha is no longer accepting responses."